# Shared UI component

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-pack, uswds

I'm working on a project where I'm creating a Shareable UI component for my team. This project is built using `Angular CLI` and is using the USWDS framework.

So far I have been successful in creating a custom `npm package` on a private npm repository and adding it to our main project via our `package.json`. This particular `npm package` is considered a core package (and will be required for all project teams), which includes `peer dependencies` of the USWDS (and associated dependencies of the USWDS like `bourbon`, `bourbon-neat`), the project's custom `scss` (including overrides for `core` USWDS styles, and a header component (which is based on the standard USWDS header).

The issue I'm having is related to the image page in my `header.component.html`. The path that I'm currently using is `./assets/uswds/img/close.svg`, which works when the header is part of the main project. The images are in the `node_modules` directory for the USWDS package, which would make it a sibling to my custom package. Additionally, the image directory has been added to the `angular-cli.json` so it the images are available when we run `ng serve`.

How would I update the file path so it is displaying correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In the shareable component library, copy the USWDS images in the angular.json assets into the libraries `assets` directory like this

```
   {
      "glob": "*",
      "input": "node_modules/uswds/dist/img",
      "output": "assets/uswds/dist/img"
   }
```

When the library is packaged up, the USWDS images will be part of it in the `dist` directory.

Then you can link to an image in your HTML using this path `assets/uswds/dist/img/close.svg`